# BoundGlobalError when submitting a Task (Descartes Labs)

Tags: descartes-labs-platform

I have written a deployment function to run using Descartes Labs' Task module. My Task group definition is:

```
# define a new task group
tasks = dl.Tasks()
async_func = tasks.create_function(
    f=save_training_samples,
    name='get-training-timeseries',
    image='us.gcr.io/dl-ci-cd/images/tasks/public/py3.7:v2021.01.27-1-g371bb0bf',
    maximum_concurrency=10
)
```

When I run the asynchronous function in a for-loop over a list of points at which to pull imagery, I get the error:

`BoundGlobalError: Illegal reference to one or more global variables in your function: ['dl', 'get_features', 'get_sentinel2_cloudmasked', 'gpd', 'np', 'pd', 'pickle']`

What does the error mean? `get_features` and `get_sentinel2_cloudmasked` are other functions in the Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running code with the DL Tasks API, tasks will only recognize the functions and imported packages that are contained within the main function (argument `f` within `tasks.create_function`, or that are imported into the `tasks.create_function` as modules.

Since `get_features` and `get_sentinel2_cloudmasked` are functions within your notebook, you will need to put those function definitions within the `save_training_samples` function in order for the task image to find them. For the other imports (`gpd`, `np`, `pickle`, etc.), these are likely currently imported at the top of your notebook. These imports also need to be moved into the `save_training_samples` function.

If your script is importing other functions, say from a utils file, you can point the task to these files by including them into the `modules` argument within `tasks.create_function`. For example, you might have an import statement within your `save_training_samples` function that says `from utils import function_name`, which is importing the function `function_name` from a `utils.py` file. In order for the task image to find this function, you would include `utils` as a module in `tasks.create_function`, like so:

```
# define a new task group
tasks = dl.Tasks()
async_func = tasks.create_function(
   f=save_training_samples,
   name='get-training-timeseries',
   image='us.gcr.io/dl-ci-cd/images/tasks/public/py3.7:v2021.01.27-1-g371bb0bf',
   maximum_concurrency=10,
   include_modules=['utils'],        # include custom modules
)
```

You will also need an `__init__.py` file that lives in the same directory as the `utils.py` file, so that the task image will recognize this as a module.